# Xamarin - ListView showing all property values but one

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, .net-5

I have a Content Page in which I want to show an invoice, for that I have two listviews.

The first one contains the name of the customer, the date and the total cost.

The thing is to get the total cost I have used Shell navigation with parameters and it works fine just not in the listview.

So here is my ViewModel

```
  [QueryProperty(nameof(Total), "total")]
    public class InvoiceViewModel : BindableObject
    { 
        string _total;
        public string Total
        {
            get => _total;
            set
            {
                _total = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value ?? string.Empty);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public InvoiceViewModel()
        {
            _oListOrders = new ObservableCollection<CrOrder>();
            GetListCart();
        }


        private ApiService _apiService = new ApiService();
        public List<Invoice> _oListCart = new List<Invoice>();
        public ObservableCollection<CrOrder> _oListOrders;

        public List<Invoice> ListCart
        {
            get => _oListCart;
            set
            {
                _oListCart = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private async void GetListCart()
        {
            // call database here
            var customerId = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentPropertiesService.GetCustomer());

            var customer = await _apiService.GetCustomerById(customerId, CurrentPropertiesService.GetToken());

            _oListCart.Add(new Invoice
            {
                Name = customer.Data.Name,
                Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Total = Convert.ToDecimal(_total),
                ListOrders = await GetListOrders()
            });
        }

        private async Task<ObservableCollection<CrOrder>> GetListOrders()
        {
            // call database here
            var cartId = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentPropertiesService.GetCart());

            var orders = await _apiService.GetOrdersByCart(cartId, CurrentPropertiesService.GetToken());

            ObservableCollection<CrOrder> collection = new ObservableCollection<CrOrder>(orders.Data);

            return collection;

        }
    }
```

Here is what I have in my View

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#A7A7A7">
            <Label Text="{Binding Total}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
            <ListView x:Name="ListViewCart" ItemsSource="{Binding ListCart}" HasUnevenRows="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Invoice">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="2" BorderColor="Gray">
                                <Grid Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="150" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Nombre del Cliente:" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Fecha Compra:" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Date}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Monto Total:" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat='{0:N2}€'}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="Detalle Compra" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <BoxView Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Color="Gray" HeightRequest="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

                                    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="Nombre" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="#9C2424"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="Monto" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="#9C2424"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="Cantidad" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="#9C2424"/>

                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                        <ListView x:Name="ListViewOrders" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOrders}" HasUnevenRows="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" >
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:CrOrder">
                                                    <ViewCell IsEnabled="False">
                                                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0" MinimumHeightRequest="50">
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Reference}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="12" />
                                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:N2}€'}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="End" FontSize="12" />
                                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Quantity}"  TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="End" FontSize="12"/>
                                                        </Grid>

                                                    </ViewCell>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListView>...
```

And on my ContentPage I don't have anything

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class InvoicePage : ContentPage
    {

        public InvoicePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //BindingContext = new InvoiceViewModel();
        }
    }
```

So on my View I have put a label to check what I thought was happening. So the label shows right the total but when I use the ListView binging it doesn't work I don't know why it is null there.

[image]

As you can see the label works fine but where it sais "Monto Total" it shows nothing. Please help I don't know what is going on. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I tried naming the `Total` property different and then when I add my `Invoice` entity to my list I do this

```
Total = Convert.ToDecimal(TotalCart),
```

But it isn't working eitherway. I don't know why the first time it returns the value fine but the second it doesn't.

After debbuging I have realized when getting the total property that the first time when `GetListCart` is being called the value is null and the second time, when the label text is set it returns the correct value. Why is this happening?

Comment: I have checked the code. The stringformat in xaml is a correct  format. According to the code, the `_total` is the value you set for the `Total` property. How did you get the value for `_total` in `GetListCart`?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I get it from the query property. I pass the parameter with shell navigation

Comment: Have you tried to update the `_total` value when it changed through `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I'm going to try that

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Still null, I will just get that value from the database. Thanks!